# mvc3 forms authentication across sub-domains in single application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, subdomain, single-sign-on

Similar to this question:
[Single Sign-on - MVC3 and Webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934947/single-sign-on-mvc3-and-webforms)

I have a MVC3 application with custom routing that takes the first part of the sub-domain URL and uses it as a variable. So, for example, test1.mydomain.com gives my controllers the variable subdomain a value of test1. If we type in test2.mydomain.com, then the controllers receive "test2".

The problem is with authentication (using built-in forms auth). If I log on while on test1.mydomain.com and then navigate to test2.mydomain.com, it doesn't persist the the log on to that subdomain. Of course if I navigate back, it shows that I'm logged in.

I've tried the following two solutions, but they didn't work:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx
[Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains)

I've added a Machine Key to the app, though I'm not sure if this was necessary.
NOTE: I'm still on the dev box so the domain is coming up localhost:2510. So, for example, my subdomains are test1.localhost:2510 and test2.localhost:2510. I've tried to manually set the auth cookie domain to "localhost" and that doesn't work. I'm telling you this in case the problem is that I'm running from "localhost". I'm in the process of testing it under a different binding (mysite.com). I'll update if that works. For now though, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After I created the mysite.com domain name locally (iis binding) and surfing to my application there, I found that the solution given on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx works perfectly. Shoot me a msg if you need any more clarification. Localhost can't be used when trying to persist authentication between sub-domain on a single MVC3 application.

Comment: Could you explain what you did to set up the domain name locally please.  Did you have to edit your hosts file? Thanks